# Syntax Error found in XBF generation

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I installed Windows 8.1 Pro and visual studio 2013 ultimate
I created new project in C# and VB and Built it without changing anything and I got this error:

Syntax Error found in XBF generation    HubPage.xaml

I noticed that the error occurs in HubPage ,PivotPage but not in Blank Page

Please help me cause I do not know what is happening as I did not change anything from the ready templates

Comment: No body tried to answer my question, I ended up using Blank page but still I did not try using the Pivot or Hub Controls which could be the cause.

Answer (score 0):

I had this earlier, on a machine that had *just* been upgraded from Windows 8.0 to Windows 8.1. Rattling through the Windows Updates to bring the machine up to date resolved the issue for me